# Storing large amounts of database information i.e Achievements/Collectibles in a mySql Database

Tags: mysql, database, multiplayer

What is the best way of storing large amounts of data for a multiplayer game i have a database to store the important information such as log in info and contact details but i am stuck when it comes to recording inventory items and achievements. I am fairly new to databases and the only solution i can think of is to either create id's for each individual item and store which item id's a player has or create a column in the table for each individual item/achievement.
There may also be a collectible card element to the game and need the solution to store which 
cards an account owns. What is the best way to go about this?

Edit: To be more specific I'll explain it with cards; say the game contains 300 Unique cards and a player collects them as they play the game, how would i store the data of what cards a player owns, Baring in mind the cards are not collected in a linear fashion IE players unlock the cards at random and can have multiple copies of each card.

Edit 2: Just to avoid any confusion the database doesn't need to store the information on each card, it just needs to save an id that can be accessed via php, to unlock the items on log in.

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are a lot of different solutions but it's going to be easiest to help you pick one if we have a better idea of exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Edited to be more specific.

Comment: "Large Amounts" is how many billions of achievements?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're talking about a [many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) relationship (possibly several).

Assuming you have

```
Players
--------
player_id, name, etc etc
```

You would want to add

```
Achievements
--------
achievement_id, description, type,
```

and tie them together with

```
Player_achievements
--------
player_id, achievement_id
```

Depending on the level of complexity, if you have many types, you might want a type lookup table (card, achievement, collectible, etc)  OR you might want to put each of those into its own table if the data on each one is different.

Edit: saw your edit, you mention that you could just store an ID in the db and keep the info related to each of 300 cards in php code? No, I wouldn't do that. I would store the card info, and any rules/powers/whatever in the database. Then you can add, change, etc without having to alter the code. like:

```
Cards
--------
card_id, description, bonus, damage, damage_type, i_have_no_idea, im_making_these_up
```

and tie them together with

```
Player_cards
--------
player_id, card_id, quantity
```

Note I added quantity to player_cards since you mention a player can have multiple.

Comment: How would i store the id's though i am new to MySql because one account could have up to 300 id's how would store all id's and access them, i get creating two tables one for cards one for the players details but how would i store which actual id's a player owns without making 300 columns.

Comment: That's the third table I described. It has player_id and card_id, so a certain player might have 300 records in that table, one for each card.  And you get them all by `select card_id from player_cards where player_id= ? `